# How to check if input value equals any of the following then check the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some working script but I know there is a way to clean this up with an if statement but I can never get it working.

I'm trying to find a way for it to search if the value is equal to 2, 3, or 5. If it is, then check the checkbox.

Here is the script:

```
var num = 5;
$('input:checkbox[value="' + num + '"]').attr('checked', true);
var num = 2;
$('input:checkbox[value="' + num + '"]').attr('checked', true);
var num = 3;
$('input:checkbox[value="' + num + '"]').attr('checked', true);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="select">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="5">
</div>
```

[This fiddle shows it working](https://jsfiddle.net/d393savL/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use map for multiple value. Push the value in single array and use map on the arry to checke the value.

```
[5,2,3].map(function(num){
    $('input:checkbox[value="' + num + '"]').prop('checked', true);
})
```

Working Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/d393savL/1/

**PS: Changed the answer used prop as suggested by @Mike thanks :)**

Comment: From [the documentation for attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr): ***To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the `checked`, `selected`, or `disabled` state of form elements, use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.***

Answer (score 2):

Using `.forEach()`:

```
var values = [2, 3, 5];
values.forEach(function(value) {
   $('input:checkbox[value="' + value + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

This would "loop" through your `values` variable, trying to check any `checkbox` with the matching values.

Comment: `forEach` is definitely a better idea than using `map` for side effects.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan what makes forEach better than map? I've never used either before.

Comment: `map` is meant to take an array and "map" the values to a different one, returning an array with those different values. Thus, if you see `map` used without the return value, it's likely not being used correctly. `forEach` is meant to take an array and iterate over it, without a return value. In this case, iteration is what we want, not mapping, so it is better. That's just my opinion though, and `forEach` support in older browsers is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all input checkboxes and check the value attribute

```
$(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index, item){
    switch($(item).attr('value')) {
        case '2':
      case '3':
      case '5': $(item).prop('checked', true);
      break;

    }

  })
})
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/d393savL/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the others, but taking advantage of selectors. You can have multiple selectors in a single string, so it's easier to let jQuery to do the loops.

```js
$(function () {
  $(':checkbox[value="2"],:checkbox[value="3"],:checkbox[value="5"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_check[]" value="5">
</div>
```